# View output from multiple laptops on one monitor at the same time

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I have two (or multiple) laptops and a single monitor. I could use a KVM switch to switch between laptops. I have a follow up question. Is there anyway i could view screens of multiple laptops on one monitor 'at the same time'. I want to watch video/music on one of the laptops while i work on the other all at the same time (on the same monitor). Is this (or something similar) possible?

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop software.

Windows comes with Remote Desktop.
RealVNC can do this also.

Depending on network speeds there could be lag.
Other software exists.